# Parsing Ajax using python

Tags: python, ajax

I use BeautifulSoup4 to parse normal HTML page contents.Is it possible to parse ajax contents using BeautifulSoup4 in python??

Comment: `BeautifulSoup4` is for parsing HTML, not downloading content. What do you use to download a webpage?

Comment: Use the requests module for fetching an URL and then feed the result into BeautifulSoup. Downvoted.

Comment: @btouge: i edited my question.. am i clear now?

Comment: AJAX content? AJAX is a client-side thing, Python runs server-side. Yet another down vote?

Comment: @ user2799617: thanks for yr downvotes.. its well showing off that you are expert.. my wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is beautiful for working with HTML. To work with dynamic pages, you'll need a headless browser or at least an embedded javascript runtime. Take a look at [Ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/), a webkit web client written in python.

> Executing javascripts inside webkit frame is one of the most interesting features provided by Ghost.

Comment: @ miku :I am working on with your suggestion.. thank you...